# Get DNS servers CLI ubuntu desktop 20.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

I've set up servers using netplan. If I run **nslookup**  or **networkctl status --all** none of them retrieve the Nameservers.

- `nslookup blahblah.com`

```
Server:     127.0.0.53         # what is this?
Address:    127.0.0.53#53      # what is this?

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.remoteserver.com
Address: 52.128.23.153
```

- `networkctl status`

```
                          Type: wlan
                         State: routable (unmanaged)
                        Driver: rtl8821ae
                        Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                         Model: RTL8821AE 802.11ac ...
             WiFi access point: ...
                       Address: 192.168.8.109
                                a::b:c:d:6dff
                       Gateway: 192.168.8.1 (...)
```

Only **nm-cli** shows the servers:

```
nmcli device show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.8.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.4.4
```

Now, this is fine but what is the method to get the DNS servers when nm-cli (and also network manager) are not installed? Why do the other commands result useless although both should return the DNS server?

Comment: "Address:    127.0.0.53#53      # what is this?" That is evidence that dnsmasq is running and has the answer and, in this case, a resolver outside of your own system wasn't required.

Comment: @chili555 how come a resolver outside the system isn't required, when i typed an address Ive never typed before...?